# My checkbox columns don't work for associations in Netzke?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, netzke

Ive setup a many-to-many relationship through a join table, with components similar to the boss_clerks demo. (Ive included a contrived example). Everything works except the CheckColumn on the association `member__available` which is a `:boolean`.

On a grid where the booleans are attributes of the models, and not of an association, the checkcolumn works fine. But, when I specify a boolean from an association, like `member__available`, then the checkcolumn doesn't display. To get checkcolumn to work I specify the `xtype` and other column config manually. Then the checkbox will update from false to true, but once true will not respond to "unchecking", it becomes stuck in the true state (which is now saved in the database).

extjs 4.2.0.663
netzke-core 0.9.0
netzke-basepack 0.9.0
rails 3.2.11

Thanks!

```
class Member
  has_many :teams, :through => :team_members
  attr_acessible :available
end

class Team 
  has_many :members, :through => :team_mebers
end

class TeamMember
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :member
  attr_acessible :role
end

class TeamGrid 
    def configure(c)
        c.model = "Team"
    end
end

class TeamMemberGrid
    def configure(c)
        c.model = "TeamMember"
        c.columns = [
            :member__name,
            :member__specialty,
            { name: :member__available, editor: { xtype: :checkbox}, xtype: :checkcolumn, attr_type: :boolean },
            :role
        ]
    end
end
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug in netzke-basepack. I'll fire a bug report on GitHub and will try to address it asap.

Comment: I take back my comment. Originally netzke-basepack somewhat supported "nested attributes", but now the preferred way is to use virtual attributes on the model as described in the proposed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be easy to solve with virtual attributes, something like:

```
class TeamMember
  delegate :available, to: :member, allow_nil: true

  def available=(v)
    member && member.update_attribute(:available, v)
  end
end


class TeamMemberGrid
  def configure(c)
    c.model = "TeamMember"
    c.columns = [
      :member__name,
      :member__specialty,
      { name: :available, attr_type: :boolean, read_only: false },
      :role
    ]
  end
end
```

Netzke by default makes virtual attributes read-only, that's why you need `read_only: false`.